# Strange `Set` behaviour in dart when overriding `hashCode` getter

Tags: dart

My code is as follows:

```
class Foo {
  double field = 0;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other is! Foo) return false;
    return field == other.field;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => field.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  final set = Set<Foo>();
  final variable = Foo();

  set.add(variable); // add variable to Set
  variable.field = 1; // change variable
  for (var v in set) print(v == variable); // true: content of the Set changed as expected
  print(set.contains(variable)); // false: I would expect true here
}
```

Why `set.contains` giving `false` in the last line?

Comment: [Do not modify elements in a way which changes their equality (and thus their hash code) while they are in the set. Some specialized kinds of sets may be more permissive with regards to equality, in which case they should document their different behavior and restrictions.](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.4/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html)

Comment: If you want to update a value stored in a set you can remove the value from the set, then update it, and then place the updated value back into the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Set` by default is a `LinkedHashSet`, which stores elements by hash code. The container has no way to know when an element is mutated and has a new hash code. Consequent lookups with the mutated element therefore will fail because no element exists with the updated hash code.

The moral is that you must not mutate elements in a `Set` (and similarly must not mutate keys in a `Map`) without first removing them and re-adding them after.

This also is why [overriding `operator ==` and `hashCode` is discouraged for mutable classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes).